# reading comprehension

Tags: readings

> 制服を着てしまうと組織の一員となって個人は消える。職業声も同じです。仕事に個性などいらないということでしょうか。しかし一日の三分の一は仕事をしているわけですから、**その時間を制服のような借り物の声で話すこと**は、気楽ではあるかもしれないけれど、心身には大きな負担であろうと思います。

The bold sentence confuses me, I don't know what it means by 時間を, because it seems there is no verb linked to を.

Comment: You have been asking questions on this site for a while now. Have you gathered yet that you need to be a bit more specific for your questions to be received well by others?

Comment: sorry,I am trying to revise it

Answer (score 1):

> その時間を制服のような借り物の声で話すこと

The verb here is 話す. その時間 is the を-marked part, and 【【制服のよう】な【借り物】】の声 is a で-marked part. The entire phrase to that point modifies こと.

```
その  時間          を     制服    の       よう    な
that time(duration) (acc.) uniform -type-of resembl-ing

借り   物        の       声    で          話す  こと
borrow -ed-thing -type-of voice by-means-of speak -action
```

"[The act of] talking then in the voice [of someone] borrowing a uniform" (metaphor for someone who was deputized?), I guess. The のs here seem a bit abstract.

Comment: Do you think 時間を話す make any sense?I search this phrase in google and turn out nothing.I think change を into に will make sense

Comment: Hmm, good point, that wouldn't work as a direct object in English, either. So I guess it must go with な, but I'm a little too tired to puzzle it out at the moment.

Comment: I think this を corresponds to this definition from Daijirin:「④動作・作用の行われる時間・期間を表す。「この一年―無事に生きてきた」「今―盛りに咲く」」

Comment: @JimmyYang yes, that makes sense and I can't think of anything better. I edited the translation accordingly.

Comment: @JimmyYang - It still sounds a bit strange with 話す. 話して過ごす would go more naturally with を.

Comment: Although we have no choice but to consider this を is linked to 話す, "時間を話す" is indeed a weird expression. Normally, this part has to be something like その時間を制服のような借り物の声で過ごすことは or その時間を制服のような借り物の声で話しながら過ごすことは.

Comment: I don't think the sentence has anything to do with being deputized. It just compares speaking in a certain way (in a way that's perhaps unnatural to you) with wearing a uniform. 制服のような借り物の声 ~ a "borrowed" voice which is like a uniform. You don't borrow the uniform. You "borrow" the voice, which the writer says is similar to wearing a uniform.